# Accessing private instances using VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn

Is it possible to access private resources in a VPC via a VPN?

I looked at the solution using bastion hosts but I prefer a solution where I use a VPN client, enter my credentials and have full access to private resources in VPC.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. You can either set up a site-to-site VPN using Amazon's VPN endpoint product or you can stand up your own OpenVPN server in your VPC.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can setup VPN, this link may be helpful https://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/04/10/quickly-connect-to-your-aws-vpc-via-vpn/

Or you just can use Amazon VPN endpoint, as @EEAA said before.